# How to create a single line command in yii CGridView?

Tags: php, frameworks, yii

here is the code:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
....
....
'columns'=>array(
    ....
    ....
    array(
    'name'=>'owner_name', 
    'value'=> 'isset($data->owner)?$data->owner->getProfile($data->owner->u_type)->e_last_name:"UnKnown"'),
    ....
    ....
    ),
),
```

));

the variable $data->owner->u_type has the value of 'e' or 'w' and the whole $data->owner->getProfile($data->owner->u_type) is an object. I want to have

```
'value'=> 'isset($data->owner)?$data->owner->getProfile($data->owner->u_type)->***$data->owner->u_type***_last_name:"UnKnown"')
```

So I can handle both e_last_name and w_last_name. The problem is that the eval function shows a parse error. I know that I can declare a function and do this task in that function. I wanna know is there any way to do this straight in the code?

Answer (score 0):

```
'value'=> isset($data->owner) ? $data->owner->getProfile($data->owner->u_type)->e_last_name : "UnKnown",
```

Or I do not understand you?

Comment: $data->owner->u_type is 'e' or 'w'. that means I don't know which variable is declared: e_last_name or w_last_name? I think I should change e_ in a way that access ?_last_name and ? is in $data->owner->u_type.